# Flutter Process.run() with runInShell: true runs the command in shell but when compiled to exe opens a new window

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-io

I have a function that uses the Windows ping command:

```
ProcessResult process = await Process.run(
  'ping',
  ['-n', '1', '-l', '1', '-w', '100', host.name],
  runInShell: true,
);
```

When I run it in Visual Studio Code it works normally. But When I compile it to Windows executable and it runs my function, it opens a new window of my app instead of opening cmd in the background and executing the ping command in it.

Is there a reason and possibly a solution why it does that?

Comment: have you tried `runInShell=false`? What happens? The behaviour your are seeing is what is mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: I looked more into it and it looks like when I run the app in Visual Studio Code it works fine because VS Code runs it through a command line unlike just opening the executable. It works as intended when I run the executable through a cmd. I tried `runInShell=false` and it has the same result. Now, is there a way I can just run the executable without a cmd?